# Dishwasher supply line leak

Tags: plumbing, water, dishwasher

I deinstalled my old dishwasher as I getting a replacement.  The supply line has been dripping ever since. I double checked the supply line was firmly closed and tightened the nut from the water supply to the dishwasher nut - but still leaking - help!!

[image]

Comment: The valve probably has calcium buildup, sometimes opening and closing will clear it, not always tho.

Answer (score 1):

Supply valve is not fully shutting off.

Consider replacing it.

If that is not a task you wish to do now get a plug for  the line to temporarily stop the drip until new DW is installed

[image]